# jQuery: input:checkbox change() only fired on browser reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this seems ridiculously easy, but I cannot find where the problem lies.

This is the part of html that I am trying to control using jQuery:

```
<table id="my_table" class="tableCommon">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="control" colspan="3"><a name="SOME_NAME"></a><input value="1" name="SOME_NAME" disabled="" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
                        <span class="checkbox-label">This is a checkbox label</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

This is the jQuery part (the opening script tag follows table's closing tag):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //other stuff before it
    function changedValue(newVal){
        jQuery('table#my_table tr td:first-child input:checkbox').each(function(){
            if(this.name !== newVal){
                this.attr('checked', false);                
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery('table#my_table tr td:first-child input:checkbox').change(changedValue(this.name));
});
```

I have debug breakpoints at both the selector with `change()` listener and the if statement inside `changedValue` function. When one tries checking the check-boxes, none of the breakpoints are reached. Code does stop at them when on page reload. There are other handlers in the same jQuery block that I omitted but which work fine (on event basis).

jQuery version used is 1.4.2
browser: Firefox Developer Edition 62.0b12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('table#my_table tr td:first-child input:checkbox').change(changedValue(this.name));
```

You are **invoking** the method `changedValue` here, because you are calling it with arguments.  So what is being bound as a handler is the result returned from the function, which is `undefined`.  You should modify your binding to bind properly.

```
//accept in the event that happened
function changedValue(e){
    //get the value off of the element that was changed, which exists on the event
    var newVal = e.target.name;

    //reduced the each to a filter
    jQuery('table#my_table tr td:first-child input:checkbox')
      .filter(function(){ return this.name != newVal; })
      .attr('checked', false);
}

//give change the function reference
jQuery('table#my_table tr td:first-child input:checkbox').change(changedValue);
```

Comment: Or he could `.change(e => {changedValue(e.target.name))})`

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu true, but then you've introduced an extra anonymous method that isn't really necessary (given the use case he has shown so far).

Comment: I've updated it with something that makes more sense (at least to me). Point here being: rather than have the logic of getting the param from the event in the function, do it where you're calling it from. This way you'll be able to call that function from different scenarios, some of which might not imply an event.

Comment: That's what I'm agreeing with.  You only need to do that if you have other parts of your logic that you want to pass in the value, without an event.  But given the question so far, that's not necessary in this use case.  I disagree that creating an extra method should be the standard, without taking into consideration the rest of the logic.

Comment: @Taplar I got it, thank you - I needed to pass a function reference instead of fucntion return value. The if statement breakpoint is only touched once, but `jQuery('table#my_table tr td:first-child input:checkbox')` length yields three. Is this expected? :-)

Comment: I happen to disagree on this one. Practice shows, no matter how good you are, you never can anticipate all usages and scenarios in which your code will be used. So I'll always keep the logic of extracting the info needed outside of the function, even if it's used only once. This way I know that whenever I need to reuse one of my methods, I don't have to worry about feeding events to it, if all it needs is a name. It's about scalability. Have the door open at all times if i don't need it closed.

Comment: @vasigorc that selector is matching against multiple rows, and since you are using checkboxes, multiple of them can be checked.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu We'll just have to agree to disagree on that one, :)

Comment: @Taplar you've tackled the described issue so it is solved. About your comment - I am trying to get all first `td`s in each `tr` and only allow one to be checked. Could you please tell me whether I should modfy my selector to that end?

Comment: If the name of every checkbox is different, then your logic is finding all the checkboxes that do not have the same name as the checkbox that was just changed, and unchecking them.  Just reading the logic it looks like you have what you want.